How do I find missing Wifi in 22.04 and 24.04 LTS?
I created a bootable USB stick and used it to install Ubuntu on a Windows 10 HP notebook in dual-boot mode. The machine worked well for several years but developed hard drive problems recently.
Hence, I used the same USB stick and the same image of 22.04 to install Ubuntu 22.04 on an Acer Windows 11 laptop in dual-boot mode. On this machine, unlike the last one (HP), Wifi is absent. This does not seem to be a hardware issue, as Wifi works fine when the machine is running Windows.
Anyway, thinking that switching to a newer iteration of Ubuntu might solve the problem, I flashed 24.04 LTS on the USB Stick and installed it on my new Acer laptop. There was no change. That is, there was still no Wifi.
I am attaching an image of the Settings -> Networks screen in Ubuntu 24.04.

In addition to Wifi being missing, Bluetooth cannot be turned on. When I try to turn it on, I find the machine stuck in Airplane mode. When I turn off Airplane mode, it turns on by itself very shortly after.
PS. I ran a diagnostic code as advised by @user535733
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info

The output was this:
2024-05-15 20:01:00--  https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info
Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’

...

See My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?. Please edit your question above to provide the information.

I tried to run the code but did not succeed. Have provided the output above.

You need internet access to run the script. Use phone tethering or ethernet.

Even phone tethering does not work. Wifi is simply absent from Settings, as if the hardware doesn't exist. But it does - wifi works fine when I run Windows. A friend has advised me to plug into ethernet before attempting those things. I shall do that as soon as I can find a cable.
